# Problem with changing Apple ID on iPhone

Tags: icloud, apple-id

My original Apple ID was associated with an email address that is not valid anymore. I updated my Apple ID to a real valid email. I managed to update it successfully with everything except iCloud on my phone. The App Store, iTunes, and everything else on my phone has the correct ID except iCloud.

When I try to delete my iCloud account from **Setting > iCloud > Delete Account**, I am asked to enter my password for the old email address, when I do so, I get a reply that the password is wrong.  When I try to retrieve it, I am asked for my date of birth, and then told that it is also wrong.

How can I change to my new Apple ID?

Answer (score 2):

One new feature of iOS 7 is an activation lock - and this means that you can't sign out or erase the device without entering the proper password for the account to which your device has been locked.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5818

Towards the bottom of the article, it has a link to use My Apple ID web page to check and reset your password if you have forgotten it.

- https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/

Presumably, if you can't reset the password, you might need to reach out to Apple directly and see if there is an administrative process such as mailing them proof of purchase or correctly answering questions about past billing events to have them reset the account password.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the account on the iPhone.  Go to iCloud settings and tap on the top line (the one with your old Apple ID). Then enter your new login details on the following screen.

Comment: I tried doing that, but my old ID is grayed out and it won't let me make any changes.

Comment: Actually - this user is likely locked out on iOS 7 due to the activation lock forcing the account to relinquish control before it allows them to sign out of Find My Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You change the Apple ID and password as described in App Store. After that you delete old Apps whichever software you want to update. If you attempt to update old apps, it will ask for the password to the old Apple ID.

Therefore, after deleting the old apps, you need to go to the App Store search and download the software again using the new Apple ID where the new password will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off find my phone.  It will ask for password of old id. Entered pass for old id(email address I no longer use) and it turned off find my phone.  Hit home then settings then iCloud just fill in new id and pass.  Took me a bit but figured it out.